# How to get VS Code to propose more limited rename?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, F2 rename on purely local C++ symbols is fine, but trying it on a symbol with wider scope, results in a very aggressive scope of suggested renaming, going as far as suggesting to rename unrelated symbols with the same name *in the system header files*. These typically default to unchecked, but at one point, it did rename an unrelated symbol with the same name in a project header, so it would be nice if the default could be dialed down a bit. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: The *confirmed* matches are based on the type information. It should be accurate. If it renamed something unrelated, report it to the vendor (Microsoft). Or at least include a [mcve] in the question so we can try it out.

Comment: @rustyx Right, I believe you that it is based on the type information, and will be accurate where everything uses types in a simple way, but not everything in C++ does use types; I don't remember the exact case where it got the confirmed match wrong, but it was untyped preprocessor code. Is there no way to tell VS Code 'in future, just rename the thing I asked you to rename, instead of trawling through the system header files looking for conceivably related things'?

Comment: Could you share the extension you are using that does this? also I believe it would be in the settings.json file, but I'm struggling to find something similar on my version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't with vscode, it's the linter vscode is using.
The easiest way to try to resolve the problem is using a different more advanced c++ linter. It's what I did to resolve a similar issue using golang.

Maybe the below link will help you find your new favorite linter.

https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/5b397d/what_c_linter_do_you_use/

PS: There is probably a setting that can edit the linter like what I am posting below, but based off of what you're asking, it may be difficult to find the right regex or whatever you need. It'd probably be best just to switch linters and then maybe make an issue on their github repository if you can't find one that suis your need.

```
  "python.formatting.blackArgs": [
    "--line-length=80"
  ],
```